# Returning a result of type String (Java)

Tags: java, string, return

I have a problem returning a result of String type in Java. 
Here is the whole code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Multiplication 
{
    static Random randomNumbers = new Random();
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int answer;

public static void multiplication()
{
    createQuestion(); //display first question
    int guess; //student's answer
    System.out.print("Your answer is (-1 to quite): ");
    guess = input.nextInt();

    while(guess != -1)
    {
        checkAnswer(guess);

        System.out.print("Your answer is (-1 to quite): ");
        guess = input.nextInt();
    }   
} //end method multiplication

//create new question
public static void createQuestion()
{
    int num_1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);
    int num_2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(10);
     answer = num_1 * num_2;
    System.out.printf("How much is %d times %d?\n", num_1, num_2);
}//end method createQuestion

public static  String createResponse(boolean correct)
{
    if (correct)

        switch(randomNumbers.nextInt(4))
        {
        case 0:
            return ("Very good!");
        case 1:
            return("Excellent!");
        case 2:
            return("Nice work!");
        case 3:
            return ("Keep the good work");
        } //end switch

//otherwise, assume incorrect
        switch(randomNumbers.nextInt(4))
        {
        case 0:
            return("No. Please try again.");
        case 1:
            return("Wrong. Try once more.");
        case 2:
            return("Don't give up!");
        case 3:
            return("No. Keep trying.");
        }//end switch

}//end method createResponse

//check in the student answer correctly
public static void checkAnswer(int guess)
{
    if(guess != answer)
    {
        System.out.println(createResponse(false));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(createResponse(true));
        createQuestion();
    }

 }//end method checkAnswer
}//end class Multiplication
```

And here is the main method

```
 public class MultiplicationTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Multiplication app = new Multiplication();
       app.multiplication();
    }
```

}

The problem is in the `createResponse(boolean correct) method. Here JDE is saying that "This method must return a result of type String"`. I have mentioned there String type return. But the program is not being executed. Showing a red line under the method createResponse(boolean correct).

Does anybody where I have messed up?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have solved my problem by your suggestion.
Sorry for delayed reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler cannot assert that your method returns a String.

This is because your switch-case may fail to return anything.

You can satisfy the compiler by placing a

```
return null;
```

at the end of your method.

Comment: If you're interested why a compiler is *essentially* not able to detect if a code runs one way or the other, look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem , but that's far beyond what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the 'else' part for the 'if' and the 'default' case for the 'switch-case' in the createResponse method.

**edit**:
ok, the 'else' is not necessary, but I missed that in the first place. the indentation of the second 'switch' is confusing. please use parentheses to avoid this.

Furthermore, the compiler believes that it could happen that none of the 'case' branches will get executed since it is not aware of the `nextInt` returning Integers in the range of 0..3. you'll need to add the `default` case to satisfy the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The method `createResponse` might not always reach a return statement in your code. If none of the cases in your second switch statement applies, it will reach the bottom of the code block without returning.

Just make sure you return something at the end of the method (or find another nice solution):

```
return "";
}//end method createResponse
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because if none of the conditions in either of the switch statements were met there would be nothing to return. Try something like:

```
public static  String createResponse(boolean correct)
{
    String result = null;
    if (correct)

        switch(randomNumbers.nextInt(4))
        {
        case 0:
            result = "Very good!";
// Insert the rest of the code here, assigning to result rather than returning as above.
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is not smart enough yet to know that `nextInt(4)` may return only `0`,`1`,`2` and `3` so it assumes that for case like `5` you current code will not return anything, but if method declares that it will return some value must guarantee that some value will always be returned.

To solve this problem you can change `case 3:` to `default:`. This would make compiler assume that even for cases which are not `0`,`1`,`2` some value will be returned.

Also it seems that your code would be cleaner if you would use `else` and additional curly brackets like

```
public static String createResponse(boolean correct) {
    if (correct){
        switch (randomNumbers.nextInt(4)) {
        case 0:
            return ("Very good!");
        case 1:
            return ("Excellent!");
        case 2:
            return ("Nice work!");
        default:
            return ("Keep the good work");
        }
    } else {
        switch (randomNumbers.nextInt(4)) {
        case 0:
            return ("No. Please try again.");
        case 1:
            return ("Wrong. Try once more.");
        case 2:
            return ("Don't give up!");
        default:
            return ("No. Keep trying.");
        }
    }// end switch

}// end method createResponse
```

BTW you can simplify your code a little by using arrays which would store your responses. This way your code could look like

```
private static String[] good = { "Very good!", 
                                 "Excellent!", 
                                 "Nice work!",
                                 "Keep the good work" };
private static String[] bad = { "No. Please try again.",
                                "Wrong. Try once more.", 
                                "Don't give up!", 
                                "No. Keep trying." };

public static String createResponse(boolean correct) {
    if (correct)
        return good[randomNumbers.nextInt(4)];
    else 
        return bad[randomNumbers.nextInt(4)];
}
```

or even

```
public static String createResponse(boolean correct) {
    return correct  ? good[randomNumbers.nextInt(4)] 
                    : bad[randomNumbers.nextInt(4)];
}
```

Comment: I am still learning using Arrays. So I hope I will use your method later after learning Array chapter :)